# Applying IV theorem to practical problems

Tags: calculus

Prove using the IVT:
For all positive integers k,
$$cosx = x^k$$ has a solution

I know that the IV states at an interval $[a,b]$ some value $c$ is bound to be hit atleast once, assuming that $[a,b]$ is continuous(Please improve my explanation where needed).

So, using this logic, assuming that $0=x^k - cosx$, I have to find values of x where this would be true?

$f(0)=0 - 1$ = $-1$

$f(π/2) = (π/2)^k - 0 $

$f(π/2) > 0$

By the IVT, there should be a value C inbetween $[0,π/2]$ if I am correct?

Please correct me where possible. I think I understand the theorem but applying it to a question like this makes me believe otherwise.

Comment: You mean $f(\pi/2) = \pi^k / 2^k > 0$...

Comment: Between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ there is  AT LEAST one root $C$ .

Comment: IVT , in fullness, states that for a continuous function defined on an interval $[a,b]$, it takes all values between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over the interval $[0,1]$, $\cos(x)$ is a decreasing (and concave) function, going from $1$ to $\cos(1)<1$. On the same interval, $x^k$ is an increasing (and convex) function, going from $0$ to $1$.
It follows that
$$ \forall k\in\mathbb{N}^+,\qquad \exists!\xi_k\in(0,1): \cos\xi_k = \xi_k^k.$$

$\hspace0.5in$[image]

By applying one step of Newton's method with starting point $1$, we also have
$$ \xi_k < 1-\frac{1-\cos(1)}{k+\sin(1)}.$$

Comment: Ah, so the POI indicates $cos(c) = c^K$ I presume?

Comment: @user382540: sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct. As to writing style , you should give a definition of $f(x)$ before discussing its properties.

The derivative of $f(x)=x^k-\cos x$ is $f'(x)=kx^{k-1}+\sin x,$ which is positive for $x>0$ for any positive $k.$ So $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, and continuous, for $x\geq 0 $ and $k>0.$ And so, since $f(0)<0< f(\pi /2),$ there is a unique $x\in (0,\pi /2)$ such that $f(x)=0.$